# Create an Array from another Array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array_1 = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "B1", "B2", "B3", ..., "Z5"]
```

I want to create another array with the elements of `Array_1` that come after `"A5"`:

```
Array_2 = ["B1", "B2", "B3", ..., "Z5"]
```

I have an ugly way that subtracts two arrays to create a third array, but I feel like there is bound to be a classy ruby way of doing something that should be simple. Any help would be amazeballs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Array_1 = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "B1", "B2", "B3", "Z5"]

Array_1[Array_1.index("A5")+1..-1]
  # => ["B1", "B2", "B3", "Z5"]
```

(I suppose we should first compute `idx = Array_1.index("A5")` to make sure it's non-nil.)

**. . .**

Another way makes use of Ruby's little-used [flip-flop](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/) operator:

```
Array_1.select { |e| e=="A5" .. false ? true : false }[1..-1]
  #=> ["B1", "B2", "B3", "Z5"]
```

The expression remains `false` until `e=="A5"` is `true`, and remains `true` until the expression following the two dots is `true`. Therefore,

```
Array_1.select { |e| e=="A5" .. false ? true : false }
  #=> ["A5", "B1", "B2", "B3", "Z5"]
```

`[1..-1]` is tacked on to return this array without `"A5"`.

The flip-flop operator must be part of a conditional expression, which is why we cannot write:

```
Array_1.select { |e| e=="A5" .. false }[1..-1]
  #ArgumentError: bad value for range
```

(for `e=="A5" .. false` is treated as a normal range).

Comment: I didn't even know that flip-flop operator existed! That's awesome!

Comment: Excellent!! The flip-flop operator was just what I was looking for! Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 2):

```
Array_1.slice_when{|e| e == "A5"}.to_a.last
# => ["B1", "B2", "B3", ..., "Z5"]
```

Comment: Great! Super sweet and short!

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
arr = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "B1", "B2", "B3", "Z5"]

p arr.drop_while {|s| s != "A5" }.drop(1)
# => ["B1", "B2", "B3", "Z5"]
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

**.slice_after** takes an argument for slicing array

```
 Array_1.slice_after("A5").to_a.last
    => ["B1", "B2", "B3", "Z5"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This creates the array that your are using using a regex match.

```
array = ('A1'..'Z5').to_a.reject { |el| el.match %r/[A-Z][0, 6-9]/ }
```

Then to remove the "A(digit)" elements using another regex match.

```
array_2 = array.select { |el| el.match %r/[B-Z]\d/ }
```

This has the added benefit of not caring about order, and can separate them regardless.